# How to use multiple checkbox to filter data in Angular 2

Tags: angular, pipe, pipes-filters

I'm creating a filter page with Angular 2.
The data is being filtered depending on the checkboxes that are checked.

This is the HTML

```
    <input required type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value1" (change)="toggleFilter(kind.value)" #kind/>
    Filter option 1

    <input required type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value2" (change)="toggleFilter(kind2.value)" #kind2 />
    Filter option 2

    <input required type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="value3" (change)="toggleFilter(kind3.value)" #kind3 />
    Filter option 3


<div *ngFor="let item of (items | FilterPipe: filterFormat)">
    {{item.id}} {{item-title}}
</div>
```

This is a piece of my Item component. In the `toggleFilter()` i'm population the array `filterOptions` with the values of the checkbox.
The `get filterFormat()` returns the populated array and places it as an argument in the `Filterpipe` (which is located in the HTML)

```
filterOptions: [] = [];

toggleFilter(value: any) {

    let index = this.filterOptions.indexOf(value);

    if (index > -1) {
      this.filterOptions.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      this.filterOptions.push(value);
    }

    return this.filterOptions;
}

get filterFormat() {
   console.log('call filterFormat');
   return this.filterOptions.map(res => res);
}
```

How can I use the checkboxes as pipe arguments in able to filter the data?

Comment: Do you still need help with this question?

Comment: The real question is why are you implementing it as a pipe? This is not a job for the pipe. Do the logic inside a service or at least in your component's code.